# Putting coded domains into list to be created in Python script?

Tags: python, arcpy, domains

I have a large list of coded domains.

They are numbers like:
01.6530.01, 05.7991.08, 05.7991.01, 05.7991.06

The code will be the exact same as the description.

I've tried to make a list using:

```
FRClist = [01.6530.**01**, 05.7991.08, 05.7991.01, 05.7991.06]
```

but it gave me a syntax error on the 01 that is bolded.

So I tried to change all the values to a string, using:

```
FRCstr = str(01.6530.**01**, 05.7991.08, 05.7991.01, 05.7991.06)
```

but it still gave me a syntax error on the same bolded 01.

In the end I hope to put the list into this:

```
arcpy.AddCodedValueToDomain_management(GDBpath, "FRC", FRClist[x], FRClistp[x] )
```

I have quite a few domains which require a lot of coded values.

Comment: If by chance you already have the values in a table then you may find it easier to use the [**Table to Domain**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000025000000) tool.

Answer (score 2):

In the [Add Coded Value To Domain documentation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00170000001v000000) there are code examples that show you how to do this.  It looks like you are trying to submit a list of coded values to a function that is designed to take a coded value at a time.  I think you should change your code to iterate through your list instead.

Python will not like 01.6530.01 being treated as a number because it is not a number.  To treat it as a string I think you will need to use the str function on each value you add to the list rather than trying to turn the list as a whole into a string.

Comment: If you use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module I think they will be automatically interpreted as strings. No need to manually add quotes.

Comment: Also I believe the Table to Domain tool (`TableToDomain_management` function in arcpy) can read a CSV file directly as the input table. You'll want to separate records in a CSV file by new lines though. So if the only column you have is your list of values, put each value on its own line.

Comment: You said that you had the list in a txt file so why not use a throwaway Python script to take the values in that file and reformat with quotes or str functions onto a single line of a throwaway file that you can copy/paste into the actual script.

Comment: Why the arbitrary restriction of no external files? This is getting pretty off-topic for this site BTW.